# IBM SQL for data science course Peer-Graded Assignment

Tags: sql

hi I'm on SQL for data science course, I have a problem to connect to IBM database. If you are a person who took this course, could you explain me how did you connect with this example :

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@my-hostname:my-port/my-db-name?security=SSL
```

I can find the following information in credentials:

> ```
> port : is the database port
>
> db : is the database name
>
> host : is the hostname of the database instance
>
> username : is the username you'll use to connect
>
> password : is the password you'll use to connect
> ```

[image]

when I try to make a connection with this code I took this warnings:

> ```
> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
>                postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-310-darwin.so,
> ```
>
> 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'
> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
> or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

I cannot finish my course because of this problem. If you know the answer please share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. If you encounter these kinds of issues, try them without quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `?` to `;` and at the end add `;`.